# How can I detect when a URL rewrite has been used in Apache or IIS?

Tags: php, apache, iis, url-rewriting

**Q&A - URL Rewrite *Detection***

It's simple enough to detect whether or not the URL rewrite module is enabled in Apache 2.4 or IIS, but how does one go about detecting whether or not a rewrite was actually Used?

I've personally done some looking around to find a single solution that works in both environments, in their latest iterations - but ended up having to sort through the server's variables myself to find a difference between a non-rewritten URL and a rewritten URL.

Answer (score 0):

**Q&A - URL Rewrite *Detection***

Detecting whether or not a rewrite was actually *used* in any given request can be achieved using the following method:

```
function IsRewrite()
{
    if(!empty($_SERVER['IIS_WasUrlRewritten']))
        return true;
    else if(array_key_exists('HTTP_MOD_REWRITE',$_SERVER))
        return true;
    else if( array_key_exists('REDIRECT_URL', $_SERVER))
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
```

If a URL rewrite was not used, the aforementioned variables will not be set at all. Depending on the version of Apache, at least one of the latter two variables will be assigned, and under IIS, the first in the list will be assigned.